# Android Save EditText with Image

Tags: android, image, save, android-edittext

Right now I have a simple App that takes a picture and saves it to a folder.  I'm trying to figure out a way to have a user answer questions about each picture (I would just be using EditTexts with that).  Is there a way to connect those EditTexts with the image so that when I would open up the image on another page that i could click a button to view the information that was entered along with that image?  I have an idea on how to code everything else, just not keeping the edittexts associated with the image.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you could create a data file alongside the image that has the same name as the image file, but a different extension.

So if you are saving an image called `img1.png` you save another file alongside it called `img1.txt` which contains the data you collect from the EditText(s). How you format this data file will depend a bit on how much data you have to store, and what kind of structure the data needs to represent (if any)

Then when you load up a png to display it you'll need to also load up the txt file that shares the same name, and populate the data contained inside to some TextView or something near your ImageView.

Comment: +1 for going for the simple option instead of a database. A database would really only have an advantage if there was going to be hundreds of images.

Comment: Disagree.  A database has an advantage of being easy to add and alter information after creation, being easy to search on, and having all the information for all images in one place rather than scattered around the filesystem.  It works, but its extremely inflexible and difficult to add features to.

Comment: I am opting out of the database method (for now), something like that doesn't seem like it would be needed for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm trying to give a .txt file the same name as the image, would bundling the name of the image over the class where the .txt is created and saved be my best bet?  Thank you!

Comment: This is the method I am using and while I haven't finished it yet, I finished 2 of my 3 hurdles!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: FoamyGuy - I am stuck on the final hurdle, which is displaying the text file. I have been able to save it with the same file name (different extension) as my image file, but I am STUCK on displaying it now.  How I envision viewing the text file is in my gridview, if the image's check box is checked, and a "View" button is pushed, then the file will open.  Do you have any hints or tips that could assist me with that?  I have opened a new question for that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165968/android-display-text-file-that-shares-same-name-as-image-file) but no ideas have surfaced yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database.  Make a table that associates images with the data you want.  When you display the picture, read the info for that picture from the database and display that as well.  Either store the images directly in the db or store them in a folder and use the filename as the primary key in the database table.

Answer (score 0):

There's number of ways to accomplish this. You could use a hashmap where the String is the data they entered and int is the resourceID of the image. For persistent storage, I recommend an SQLite Database that stores the string in a column and the associated image in another.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. Save a file with the image.. Give it the same name but .txt or something. The file should probably be stored in  the location returned by [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)() . Alternatively you could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
2. Use an sqlite database
3. Save within the exif data of the image. Use the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class with setAttribute/getAttribute to save the values.