# Android Display Text File that shares Same Name as Image File

Tags: android, image, file, text, filenames

Right now I have a very simple app where I take a picture, then answer a question.  I have the file name for the picture bundled over to the question class, and then the question is saved as a Text file using that same file name (these are all saved on the SD card).  Now what I am trying to do is to display that Text File (it'll be displayed in a TextView) when that picture is selected.  So my question would be is there a way to display a Text File that shares the same name as a selected Image file in a `TextView`?  I haven't been able to find anything else out there that does something like this, though it seems like this wouldn't be an uncommon task.

My Code is below:

Creating Image File Name:

```
ImageButton button;
static int data = 0;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/MyDirectory/");    
        myDir.mkdirs();

        if (myDir.exists()) { }

        Random generator = new Random(); 
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        text.setText(fname);

        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);  
        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", fname);

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Intent is = new Intent(Home.this, Details.class);
        is.putExtras(basket);
        i.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
        startActivity(is);
        startActivityForResult(i, data); 
    }
});
```

Creating Text File Name:

```
textfileName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textFile);
Button save;
TextView question;

Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
gotBread = gotBasket.getString("key");
textfileName.setText(gotBread);

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textQuestion= question.getText().toString();

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/MyDirectory/");    
        myDir.mkdirs();

        if (myDir.exists()) { }

        detailsFile = textfileName.getText().toString() + ".txt";
        File file = new File (myDir, detailsFile);

        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            writer.write(textQuestion);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
});
```

Displaying File with Image Selected:

```
final Button viewBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.detailsBtn);

viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
        int cnt = 0;
        String selectImages = "";

        for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
            if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                cnt++;
                selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
            }
        }

        if (cnt == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select One Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if  (cnt > 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Only One Picture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (cnt == 1) {




setContentView(R.layout.details_text);
                        detailsView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayDetails); 
                        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File myFile = new File(dir, "/MyDirectory/" + "detailsFile-.txt");

                        if (myFile.exists()) {
                            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                            try {
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
                                String line;

                                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                    text.append(line);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {

                            }   
                            detailsView.setText(text);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Doesn't Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        }

                    }

            });
```

It is in the `else if` that I am trying to display the Text File in the `TextView`.

Comment: Yes. There is a way to do it. If you post your code, I am sure someone can help you out.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question and supplied the code.  Thank you!

Comment: Are there any suggestions that anyone can throw my way?  I've still been plugging away at this but to no avail.  Frustration is kicking in me in the crotch!!